# Linq to XML not getting a result

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am creating a List of structs using linq to xml.

The linq path does not find the concept elements. I have tried various formulations of this and before I give up and use xpath I am hoping someone can show me the linq way. thanks

Here is the xml

```
<response xmlns="http://www.domain.com/api">
  <about>
    <requestId>E9B73CA1F16A670C966BE2BABD3B2B22</requestId>
    <docId>09E167D994E00B0F511781C40B85AEC3</docId>
    <systemType>concept</systemType>
    <configId>odp_2007_l1_1.7k</configId>
    <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
    <contentDigest>09E167D994E00B0F511781C40B85AEC3</contentDigest>
    <requestDate>2011-10-18T09:51:28+00:00</requestDate>
    <systemVersion>2.1</systemVersion>
  </about>
  <conceptExtractor>
    <conceptExtractorResponse>
      <concepts>
        <concept weight="0.010466908" label="hell"/>
      </concepts>
    </conceptExtractorResponse>
  </conceptExtractor>
</response>
```

here is what I have

```
public struct conceptweight
{
    public string concept { get; set; }
    public string weight { get; set; }
}

List<conceptweight> list = (from c
  in d.Descendants("response")
      .Descendants("conceptExtractor")
      .Descendants("conceptExtractorResponse")
      .Descendants("concepts")
  select new conceptweight()
         {
           concept = c.Attribute("label").Value,
           weight = c.Attribute("weight").Value
         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten the namespace, which is defaulted in the root element. Try this:

```
// Note: names changed to follow conventions, and now a class
// rather than a struct. Mutable structs are evil.
public class ConceptWeight
{
    public string Concept { get; set; }
    // Type changed to reflect the natural data type
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}

XNamespace ns = "http://www.domain.com/api";

// No need to traverse the path all the way, unless there are other "concepts"
// elements you want to ignore. Note the use of ns here.
var list = d.Descendants(ns + "concepts")
            .Select(c => new ConceptWeight
                    {
                        Concept = (string) c.Attribute("label"),
                        Weight = (double) c.Attribute("weight"),
                    })
            .ToList();
```

I haven't used a query expression here as it wasn't adding any value - you were only doing `from x in y select z`, which is more simply expressed via the `Select` extension method.

Comment: ah thanks. Works fine now and certainly more elegant that building the structs by looping though xmlnodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace n = "http://www.domain.com/api";
List<conceptweight> list = (from c in d.Elements(n + "response").Elements(n + "conceptExtractor").Elements(n + "conceptExtractorResponse").Elements(n + "concepts").Elements(n + "concept")
                            select new conceptweight
                            {
                                concept = c.Attribute("label").Value,
                                weight = c.Attribute("weight").Value
                            }).ToList();
```

You forgot the namespace and the last element (`concept`). Ah and you don't need the `()` brackets in `new conceptweight` if you do the inline initialization. Ah and `Descendants` will  traverse all the "levels" of elements. If you want to traverse it "manually", use `Elements`.